# Solr sort and limit the results of a sub-query

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search

I am using Solr as my search engine and what I want to do is to sort and limit the result of a subquery. For example, let's say I have a Amazon product review datasets and I want to get all the products with title containing "iphone" OR products in the smart-phone category.

I'd write solr query something like: `"name:iphone OR category:smartphone"`. However, the problem with this is that there are too many products that are in the category of "smartphone". So I want to limit to only popular products where the popularity is defined by something like a reviewCount. So what I'd like is, for the second subquery, sort the results of that sub-query based on reviewCount and then only take topK. That is, I want to something like:

`name:iphone OR (category:smartphone AND sort:reviewCount desc AND rows=100)`

So that I can get the products that are "iphone" OR top-100 popular smart phones.

Does Solr support something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to tell you that this is not possible. Lucene-based search engines spread indexes over multiple shards. Every shard then calculates matches and scores independently. At the very end, the results become aggregated and the number of result rows is cropped. That's why subqueries do not exist here. You can only boost on the score (which should be preferred over sorting) or make two parallel requests and combine the results on the client side (which should be fairly easy with your example).